# date() to a integer php

Tags: php, date

I have to validate some values vs the last six hours, so let it like:

```
  $last_six_hours = (time() - (3600 *6));
```

If I have to compare vs a integer like 16hs, what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What does `16hs` mean? It's not a standard format for anything.

Comment: 16 hours ago? 16 o'clock today? 16 hours from now?

Comment: 4 in the afternoon, 24hrs format

Comment: To make this a better question you should not only define what inputs your validation takes, but also what outputs you expect. Do you want the function to return true if the value inputted is in the last sixteen hours? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) takes relative amounts and returns a unix timestamp:

```
$four_o_clock = strtotime('16:00:00');
if ($sometimestamp > $four_o_clock) {
    // it happened after 16:00:00 today
}
```

Comment: You're welcome - there was no reason to post another answer as yours was perfectly correct only you misunderstood the question format. :)